# Xcode plist files consistently forget type designations

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xml, xcode, plist

I have numerous Plist files that contains dictionaries in a project and I find that they reliably forget the data type of various entries and default to NSString.

For example, I might have a PLIST containing a dictionary with several keys set to a type of NSNumber, and after closing and reopening Xcode they all get defaulted to NSString.

Is this a known issue? Is there a way I can avoid it? Changing the types of dozens of values every time I restart Xcode gets pretty annoying.

Comment: Manually? It's a file in the bundle/group tree.

Comment: Try saving the plist file after you edit it, and opening it in another text editor.  Are the values getting incorrectly saved as NSStrings, or incorrectly loaded?

Comment: It appears that the file itself (JSON formatted) does not appear to have been changed. Numbers are still numbers, but Xcode says they are strings... doesn't seem to impact app at all... just an annoyance. I guess I'm headed towards a bug report for Apple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an Xcode 3 bug. The file itself does not actually get corrupted, Xcode merely interprets the file wrongly. Numbers are still numbers and the app treats them as such, but Xcode reports them as strings when opened from the Group Tree.